# How to show messages on Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Application doesn't show messages as it should.

I tried returning back with message in RoleController. Redirecting works fine, but I can't see any messages. There is multiple functions like this, none of them show messages.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate(['name' => ['required', 'min:3']]);
        Role::create($validated);

        return back()->with('message', 'Role created successfully.');
    }
```

And this code below is in admin.layout blade.

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ Session::get('message') }}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
@endif
```

I googled this many many times but can't find a solution. This worked fine month ago, but when I continued with this yesterday, it suddenly stopped working. Php version hasn't changed, it's 8.0.2. I also tried flash-messages with no help.
Sorry, not a native english speaker.

edit / I have also cleared cache with php artisan.

Comment: check if your route is under StartSession middleware

Comment: try `session` helper  in your blade file: `@if(session()->has('message'))`

Comment: @GiacomoM how do I do that? I'm fairly new with Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working. I needed to modify `Kernel.php` and remove `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` under the `protected $middlewareGroups`.

Answer (score 4):

**try this**

In **Controller**

```
return redirect()->route('admin.listing')->with('message', 'Role created successfully.');
```

In **Blade** file

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ Session::get('message') }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this...

```
@if ($message = Session::get('message'))
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: This didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Please try one time with this one

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Role created successfully.');
```

Comment: I tried, role is created but no message...

Comment: If this is not working then u can try this one
@if(session()->get('message'))
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <strong>{{ session()->get('message') }}</strong>
</div>
@endif

Comment: or u can change the variable 'message' to something else like 'success_message', etc

Comment: I checked what session contains, no message at all. Doesn't matter what is the variable name